# How to test TextInput in react-native with @testing-library/reat-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a TextInput by checking its value after entering a string, but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { TextInput } from 'react-native'
import { fireEvent, render } from "@testing-library/react-native"

test('<TextInput/>, () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render( <TextInput testID="input" /> );
  const input = getByTestId("input");
  fireEvent.changeText(input, "123");
  expect(input.value).toBe("123");
})
```

The test fails with the message:

```
Expected: "123"
Received: undefined
```

Comment: Whats is the point to test an component that is already test by the RN team? I recommend you an approach a little more near to the user, this component (TextInput) IMHO doesnt require an unit test, you may should test the interaction with other components as here says https://github.com/vanGalilea/react-native-testing/blob/master/__tests__/LoginSubmission.test.tsx

Comment: Okay, but if I wanted to then how would I get it done?

Answer (score 18):

I think your example is not working because you are not controlling the input. Try adding a `value` and an `onChangeText` function. Something like:

```
function Example() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  return <TextInput value={value} onChangeText={setValue} testID="input" />
}

test('Should apply the value when changing text', () => {
  const { getByTestId } = render(<Exampler />);
  const input = getByTestId('input');
  fireEvent.changeText(input, '123');
  expect(input.props.value).toBe('123');
});
```

Also, you need to check `input.props.value` instead of `input.value`
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to suggest a few things to assist you to get to the solution,

- Are you sure `TextInput` has a prop called `testID`? You use `getByTestId` subsequently, which needs a `data-testid` value on the element. So please make sure of this first.
- You can try finding the element in another way. Probably use `getByPlaceholderText` or similar.

Once you can get the element properly, and after the `fireEvent`, the value should certainly be updated, and assertion would succeed.

Comment: Hey, Emmanuel. Thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately, neither of them worked. I haven't found a reliable way to fire a `submit` event for a TextInput as I feel like this is the problem. Do you know how this can be done?